# How do I remove my segmentation faults in my C program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to program a calculator that converts a an infix expression to a postfix expression and then evaluates the postfix expression. I have included my code here for your reference.

My postfix code works perfectly fine as I have tested it on its own. But when I use the postfix code in my infix file for evaluation purposes, I get segmentation faults.

I have tried using gdb to debug my segfaults and it points me towards my is_operand() function in my postfix file. I backtraced to see how it got to that function, and I noticed that when my infix program calls the postfix_evaluate function, it calls this is_operand() function which gives me this error. I have no idea how to fix this issue as I'm relatively new to C coding. Would appreciate some help!

My infix.c file:

```
 #include "infix.h"
  

// evaluate expression stored as an array of string tokens
double evaluate_infix_expression(char ** args, int nargs) {
  // Write your code here
  char ** postfix = malloc(sizeof(char*) * nargs);
  postfix = inftopost(args, nargs);
  
  int count=0;
  for(int i=0;i<nargs;i++){
    if(is_openbracket(*(args+i))){
      count++;
    }
  }
  
  int infix_size = nargs - count;
  double final = evaluate_postfix_expression(postfix, infix_size);
  return final;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------

char ** inftopost(char** args, int nargs){
  char ** postfix = malloc(sizeof(char*) * nargs);
  struct double_stack* infix = double_stack_new(nargs);
  int counter=0;  
  
  for(int i=0;i<nargs;i++){
    if(is_operand(args[i])){
      postfix[counter]=args[i];
      counter++;
    }
    else if(is_openbracket(args[i])){
      double_stack_push(infix,'(');
    }
    else if(is_operator(args[i])){
      while(op_precedence(infix, *args[i], infix)){
        char flag3 = double_stack_pop(infix);
        postfix[counter]= flag3;
        counter++;
      }
      double_stack_push(infix, *args[i]);
    }
    else if(is_closedbracket(args[i])){
      int flag;
      while(!is_openbracket_stack(infix, args)){
        char flag = double_stack_pop(infix);
        postfix[counter] =flag;
        counter++;
      }  
      double_stack_pop(infix);
    }
  }
  
  int top = infix->items[infix->top-1];
  int flag2;
  
  while(is_operator(args[top])){
    int top = infix->items[infix->top-1];
    char flag2 = double_stack_pop(infix);
    postfix[counter] = flag2;
    counter++;
  }
  return postfix;
}



bool is_openbracket(char * token){
  if(token[0] == '('){
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}

bool is_closedbracket(char * token){
  if( token[0] == ')'){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

bool is_openbracket_stack(struct double_stack * input, char ** infix){
  int top = input->items[input->top-1];
  if(infix[top][0] == '('){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

bool op_precedence(struct double_stack * input, char**infix, char * token){
  int top = input->items[input->top-1];
  int top_stack_precedence =0;
  if(infix[top][0] == '^'){
    top_stack_precedence = 4;
  }else if((infix[top][0] == '*') || (infix[top][0] == '/')){
    top_stack_precedence = 3;
  }else if((infix[top][0] == '+') || (infix[top][0] == '-')){
    top_stack_precedence = 2;
  }
  
  int token_precedence =0;
  if(token[0] == '^'){
    token_precedence = 4;
  }else if((token[0] == '*') || (token[0] == '/')){
    token_precedence = 3;
  }else if((token[0] == '+') || (token[0] == '-')){
    token_precedence = 2;
  }
  
  if(token_precedence>=top_stack_precedence){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

My postfix.c file:

```
#include "postfix.h"

bool is_operator(char * token){
    if(token[0] == '+' || token[0]=='-' || token[0]== 'X' || token[0] == '/' || token[0] == '^'){
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}

bool is_operand(char*token){
  if(token[0]>='0' && token[0]<='9'){
    return true;
  }else if((token[0]=='-' || token[0]=='.') && (*(token+1)<='9' && *(token+1)>='0')){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


// evaluate expression stored as an array of string tokens
double evaluate_postfix_expression(char ** args, int nargs) {
  // Write your code here
  struct double_stack *stack =  double_stack_new(nargs);
  
  for(int i=0;i<nargs;i++){
    if(is_operand(*(args+i))){
      double_stack_push(stack,atof(*(args+i)));
    }
    
    else if( is_operator(args[i])) {
      double token, op1, op2;
      op2 = double_stack_pop(stack);
      op1 = double_stack_pop(stack);
      char operator_check = args[i][0];
      switch (operator_check){
        case  '+': 
          token = op2+op1;
          double_stack_push(stack,token);
          break;
        
        case '-':
          token = op1-op2;
          double_stack_push(stack,token);
          break;
          
        case 'X':
          token = op1*op2;
          double_stack_push(stack,token);
          break;
          
        case '/':
          token= op1/op2;
          double_stack_push(stack,token);
          break;
          
        case '^':
          token= pow(op1,op2);
          double_stack_push(stack,token);
          break;
          
        default: break;
      }
    }
  }

  return double_stack_pop(stack);
}
```

I havent included my .h files here, but I do have all necessary headerfiles and other necessary stuff.

Comment: Reduce your code down to [mcve]. During this process there is a good chance you will find your problem yourself.

Comment: You've taken the right steps by using gdb. If you get the segfault in `is_operand`, `token` most likely points somewhere where it should not. Investigate this with gdb. Set breakpoints at strategic places in your code, Execute your code step by step while examining relevant variables. In the meantime we can't help much more because your code is incomplete. We need a [mcve].

Comment: At least, most likely you have an issue with incrementing *counter* in *inftopost*. There are too many loops in it. Debug it.

Comment: Sorry bout the minimal responsible example thing, this is my first question on stackoverflow. But otherwise, I cant debug line by line because I use mobaXterm to connect to a virtual machine that I'm supposed to connect to for this. MobaXterm if I'm not mistaken, doesn't let me add breakpoints.

Comment: This is a portable enough C code, and you should be able to run it on your local machine or any other.

Comment: MobaXterm is just the terminal, GDB is the debugger. Since most probably you entered commands to let the program run, you can as well enter commands to set breakpoints.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Once gdb is running you can set breakpoints through the command "break". Look here for further info https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html

Answer (score 0):

1. `malloc(nargs * sizeof(char *))` allocates space for an array of pointers, it does not allocate space for any of those pointers. You need to do something like `postfix[i] = malloc(... * sizeof(char))` for every element of your array before trying to index into any of those strings.
2. After you assign `postfix` to the result of `malloc`, you should not reassign it (you do this on the line `postfix = inftopost(args, nargs)`). This has the effect of 'throwing away' the result of your malloc.

As a general point of guidance, you should try to only use `malloc` and `free` within initialization functions. For example, you could write the functions `create_stack` and `destroy_stack`. All other stack methods then take a stack as a first argument, and perform some operation on that stack (popping, pushing, etc.).

If you would like more elaboration on program design in C please leave a comment.